# How can I concatenate data in R based on information in a different column?

Tags: r

My dataset contains 20 related character columns liked this: X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4, X5, Y5, X6, Y6, X7, Y7, X8, Y8, X9, Y9, X10, Y10

I want to create a new column Z that contains text concatenated from the Y columns separated by a semi-colon if the X column contains specific text.

I.e., if X1 and X2 contain "a" and Y1 and Y2 contain "b" and "c" then Z would contain "b;c" using some code that specified "a"

I'm quite new to R so don't know if this is possible or not.

Comment: Please provide sample data in a reproducible form (text).

Comment: The example data can be something as simple as a couple or rows - e.g. - `data.frame(X1 = c("a", "q"), Y1 = c("b", "b"), X2 = c("a", "a"), Y2 = c("c", "c"), Z = c("b;c", "c"))` - please check if that is what you want and edit it into your question if so.

Comment: Welcome to SO, jake! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.